# C# HTTPS Website Login

Tags: c#, post, authentication, https

For a while I'm unable to login to a website trough HTTPS protocol. I've tried various methods, some either turned up with the request turning into GET or what I have got now.

My code:

```
        string credentials = "";
        string formParams = string.Format("username={0}&password={1}&remember=true", username, password);
        string cookieHeader;
        HttpWebRequest req = WebRequest.Create("https://account.mojang.com/login") as HttpWebRequest;
        req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        req.SetRawHeader("Host", "account.mojang.com");
        req.SetRawHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:61.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0");
        req.SetRawHeader("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
        req.SetRawHeader("Accept-Language", "en - US, en; q = 0.5");
        req.SetRawHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
        req.SetRawHeader("Referer", "https://account.mojang.com/login");
        req.KeepAlive = false;
        req.SetRawHeader("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", "1");
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
        req.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(formParams);
        req.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
        req.Method = "POST";
        using (Stream os = req.GetRequestStream())
        {
            os.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }
        HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
        cookieHeader = resp.Headers["Set-cookie"];
        if (resp.Headers["Set-cookie"].Contains("PLAY_SESSION")) { credentials = cookieHeader; }
        return resp.StatusCode.ToString() + Environment.NewLine + resp.Headers.ToString(); ;
```

The result, of course, should be the status code and the headers, including the cookie, but I get the following:
[The output from the function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1B3T.png)

The cookie does not registers, neither does the rememberme cookie. What am I doing wrong? I have a project with the deadline coming soon so any help will be appreciated. Thank you for understanding.

Comment: I suggest HttpClient as it’s generally easier to work with.  Having said that your code does return the status code and headers as you stated it should.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Anyways, what my code originally is intended to do is logging in and returning the cookie, but I've modified the return so it returns the full headers and the status code, however, the session cookie for the account is not registered.

Comment: If I remember correctly it’s not preferable to set the cookie header directly but rather use a cookie container.  There is a Boolean that you can set that will allow it.  Overall I still recommend using the newer HttpClient.

Comment: It’s also clear what you mean by the “cookie” is not registered.  When you make the web request you will receive a cookie.  You can include that cookie manually on the next request that is made.  HttpClient handles this for you.

Comment: Thank you for your replies once again! Solved my problems!

Comment: If I post as an answer can you mark it?  I’m almost to 1000.  :)

Comment: Go ahead for sure!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using HttpClient.  Also note that even though it’s disposable you generally should use the same HttpClient throughout your application. See: 
https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/

```
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://account.mojang.com");
        var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", username),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", password),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("remember", "true")
        });
        var result = await client.PostAsync("/login", content);
        string resultContent = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return result.Headers.ToString();
```

Comment: No problem, please also see the link I included for additional information.